# Node.js serve static HTML files with generated menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am looking for to build a very small / quick web server for a client. I know I am going to be building on top of this but for now I have the following requirements.

1. Build a menu bar based on static html file with links to each file.
2. Create a static page which allows visitors to submit a form and that form is processed and stored to a small database.

I know how to do #2. But the first part I am not sure about.

The HTML pages need to be basic HTML only. What would the best strategy be to serve these HTML pages? Should I simply serve the files like normal? Should I read the file inside node and them append it into a the equivalent of a write out in Node?

Here is what it would look like.

```
<html> 
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id='dynamicMenuBar'/>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
      users content they put into a folder
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of how the structure will be to produce this menu

```
static/
home/
    home.html
info/
    about.html
    contact.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ExpressJS, it's the de facto web app framework for node and using Pug or one of the other HTML generating view engines you should be able to do this pretty trivially.

Answer (score 0):

With [Express Js](http://expressjs.com/), you can use [Pug](https://pugjs.org/) as template language to render your static page. A pug version of your exemple :

```
doctype html
html
  head
body
 div#dynamicMenuBar
 div#content
   p users content they put into a folder
```

You can serve your static file form your web.js (name it as you want) file  with :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('home') 
})
```

If you want to dig more I recommend to have a structure like this :

```
/public/
  images/
  stylesheets/
  javascripts/
/views/
  home.pug
  about.pug
```